# kivy image button size

Tags: python, kivy

My goal is to have Buttons which are completely filled with an image. My screen is split in half. On the right hand side I would like to have nine buttons each completely filled with a different image, all buttons with same dimensions. I would like to reshape those image to fit the button, so the ratio would possibly have to change.

This is how my GUI looks right now. The images do not fit the buttons

[image]

I tried several adjustments in my kv file, but right now I am stuck.

This is my kv file.

```
RadioRoot:
<RadioRoot@BoxLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                Label:
                    size_hint_y: 4
                    text: "info about radio"
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: 1
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        BoxLayout:
                            Button:
                                text: "Previous"
                                on_press: root.previous()
                            Button:
                                text: "Play/Stop"
                                on_press: root.play_stop()
                            Button:
                                text: "Next"
                                on_press: root.next()
                Button:
                    size_hint_y: 1
                    text: "Shutdown"
                    on_press: root.shutdown()

        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                BoxLayout:


                    Button:
                        text: "Channel1"
                        on_press: root.channel(1)
                        #size_hint_y: None
                        #size_hint_x: None
                        Image:
                            source: 'swr3.png'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size_hint_x: None
                            y: self.parent.y + .5* self.parent.height -.5 * self.parent.width/self.image_ratio
                            x: self.parent.x
                            #heigth: self.parent.width/self.image_ratio
                            #heigth: self.parent.height
                            width: self.parent.width
                            keep_ratio: True
                            allow_stretch: True
                    Button:
                        text: "Channel2"
                        on_press: root.channel(2)
                        Image:
                            source: 'flux.png'
                            width: self.parent.width
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size_hint_x: None
                            y: self.parent.y + .5* self.parent.height -.5 * self.parent.width/self.image_ratio
                            x: self.parent.x

                            keep_ratio: True
                            allow_stretch: True
                    Button:
                        text: "Channel3"
                        on_press: root.channel(3)
                BoxLayout:

                    Button:
                        text: "Channel4"
                        on_press: root.channel(4)
                    Button:
                        text: "Channel5"
                        on_press: root.channel(5)
                    Button:
                        text: "Channel6"
                        on_press: root.channel(6)
                BoxLayout:

                    Button:
                        text: "Channel7"
                        on_press: root.channel(7)
                    Button:
                        text: "Channel8"
                        on_press: root.channel(8)
                    Button:
                        text: "Channel9"
                        on_press: root.channel(9)
```

This is the corresponding python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class PhilippsRadioApp(App):
    pass

class RadioRoot(BoxLayout):

    def previous(self):
        print("Previous")

    def play_stop(self):
        print("Play/Stop")


    def next(self):
        print("Next")

    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutdown")

    def channel(self, num):
        print("Channel")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PhilippsRadioApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Image tag you are using width but not size ...

try:

```
Image:
    ...
    size: self.parent.size #I think you can remove the size hints since they don't add anything...
    stretch: True #keep this one as well :)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I also set keep_ratio to False.